# etcd err: context deadline exceeded

Tags: go, grpc, etcd

When I use shell it returns ok,
but when I use golang it returns `err: context deadline exceeded`.

Why?

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "go.etcd.io/etcd/clientv3"
    "time"
)
func main()  {
    cli,err := clientv3.New(clientv3.Config{
        Endpoints: []string{"http://192.168.11.34:2379"},
        DialTimeout: 5*time.Second,
    })
    if err != nil{
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("connect etcd success!")
    defer cli.Close()

    ctx,cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(),time.Second*5)
    _,err = cli.Put(ctx,"mac","leave")
    defer  cancel()
    if err !=nil{
        fmt.Println("put etcd err:",err.Error())
        return
    }
}
```

```
connect etcd success!
{"level":"warn","ts":"2021-02-08T17:10:46.490+0800","caller":"clientv3/retry_interceptor.go:62","msg":"retrying of unary invoker failed","target":"endpoint://client-5b14f6c4-2395-4a15-9ebb-cadf5985fb06/192.168.11.34:2379","attempt":0,"error":"rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = latest balancer error: all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 192.168.11.34:2379: connect: connection refused\""}
put etcd err: context deadline exceeded
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creation of client does not guarantee that the connection is established.
It might get delayed till the first request that actually fails.

Please make sure that your server is reachable.

Comment: I am sure the server is accessible

Comment: sorry , I  turn off the firewall  ，its ok 

Answer (score 0):

Increase your timeout:

```
DialTimeout: 5*time.Second
```

Clearly this time is being exceeded if you are receiving a `context deadline exceeded` error.

Answer (score 0):

Deferring the cancel() means that the context won't be canceled until after your Println and return (during function tear-down). If the Put() call is on the edge of the timeout period that will cause the error to be reported. But calling cancel() directly after the Put() call seems to also have issues (see my recent question)